# How to create a file-like wrapper that works just like a file but auto-delete on close/__del__?

Tags: python, django

```py
def ():
   zip_fd = open(zip_path, mode="rb")
   
   file = _TemporaryFileWrapper(zip_fd)  # Like the one inside tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile
   return FileResponse(file)  # django
```

I would like my file deleted when eventually django is done responsing it

Comment: What do you mean by *"Like the one inside tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile"* ? `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` already deletes the file by default. Why can you not use that?

Comment: @DeepSpace Poster wants the file deleted when there are no more references to the handle (__del__), not when the file is closed.  At least that's how I understood the question

Comment: @FrankYellin That is also possible with `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` by using a combination of `delete=True` and `delete_on_close=False` (which has the same issue as the suggested implementation)  https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile

Comment: @FrankYellin Just noticed that `delete_on_close` was added in Python 3.12. Might be a good enough reason for OP to upgrade instead of rolling custom wrappers around :)

Comment: I'm not using NamedTemporaryFile because I already have the file.

```
_, csv_path = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix=prefix)
        df.to_csv(csv_path, index=False)

        zip_path = f"{csv_path}.zip"
        zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, "w")
        zip_file.write(csv_path, arcname=f"{os.path.basename(csv_path)}.csv")
        zip_file.close()
        zip_file = None

        zip_fd = open(zip_path, mode="rb")

        return zip_fd
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a generic wrapper will give you what you want.

```
class Wrapper(wrapped):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped

    def __del__(self):
        os.remove(self.wrapped.name)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.wrapped, attr)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm. .... I just put a try except on __del__